# капитализация в методе join

Tags: python

```
print("\t" + name.title() + "'s favorite languages are " 
       + ' and '.join(first_function[name]).title() + ".")
```

Как капитализировать только список first_function но не and?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пусть у нас есть список:

```
items = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

вы пытаетесь сделать так:

```
In [111]: ' and '.join(items).title()
Out[111]: 'One And Two And Three'
```

а правильно было бы делать так:

```
In [113]: ' and '.join(map(str.title, items))
Out[113]: 'One and Two and Three'
```

Comment: Спасибо. но не помогло)) наверное я что то не понял

Comment: Спасибо) теперь работает